# can't login to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: login

I tried to upgrade from **12.04 to 14.04** but it was a partial upgrade because the computer shut down in between. Then after the partial upgrade the system tray disappeared. Then the system tray cannot be detected message keeps coming up.  I tried to repair the package files in recovery mode but that does not help and after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> I can't even **log in**  and I'm sure that the user name and password I'm typing are correct..